# Hover reveal hidden element

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a creative webproject in class. I am trying to make a hidden textbox reveal when the user hover their mouse over an picture. Is that any way possible? Here is my html and CSS code atm. I want the div class="Textbox" to be visable when i hover over one of the pictures. is this possible to do with only HTML and CSS?

```css
body {
  background-color : black;
  font-family      : sans-serif;
  font-weight      : bolder;
  }
#logo {
  width : 100px;
  }
ul {
  padding : 0;
  margin  : 0 0 0 150px;
  }
.nav-list {
  position         : relative;
  margin           : 0;
  padding          : 0;
  background-color : red;
  min-width        : 45%;
  height           : 65px;
  left             : 50%;
  transform        : translate(-50%);
  border-radius    : 15px;
  display          : flex;
  justify-content  : center;
  align-items      : center;
  }
.nav-item {
  list-style : none;
  }
.nav-item a {
  text-decoration : none;
  display         : block;
  width           : 100px;
  padding         : 0;
  color           : white;
  font-size       : 20px;
  text-align      : center;
  font-weight     : bolder;
  }
.nav-item a:hover {
  color : black;
  }
.image-container {
  position     : absolute;
  left         : 50%;
  width        : 70%;
  margin-top   : 1%;
  transform    : translate(-50%);
  display      : flex;
  padding-left : 40px;
  min-height   : 15%;
  min-width    : 60%;
  }
.characters {
  margin-top      : 1%;
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  font-size       : 35px;
  color           : wheat;
  }
.image-container div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  }
.driver1 {
  width         : calc(100% - 40px - 0.4rem);
  height        : calc(100% - 40px - 0.4rem);
  border        : 4px solid wheat;
  border-radius : 20px;
  opacity       : 0.5;
  transition    : 0.5s;
  filter        : blur(2px) brightness(60%);
  }
.driver2 {
  width         : calc(100% - 40px - 0.4rem);
  height        : calc(100% - 40px - 0.4rem);
  border        : 4px solid wheat;
  border-radius : 20px;
  opacity       : 0.5;
  transition    : 0.5s;
  filter        : blur(2px) brightness(60%);
  }
.driver3 {
  width         : calc(100% - 40px - 0.4rem);
  height        : calc(100% - 40px - 0.4rem);
  border        : 4px solid wheat;
  border-radius : 20px;
  opacity       : 0.5;
  transition    : 0.5s;
  filter        : blur(2px) brightness(60%);
  }
div p {
  position     : absolute;
  margin-top   : -25%;
  z-index      : 1;
  color        : aliceblue;
  text-align   : center;
  padding-left : 11%;
  }
.driver1:hover {
  opacity         : 1;
  filter          : blur(0);
  background-color: wheat;
  display          : block;
  }
.driver2:hover {
  opacity          : 1;
  filter           : blur(0);
  background-color : wheat;
  }
.driver3:hover {
  opacity          : 1;
  filter           : blur(0);
  background-color : wheat;
  }
.Textbox {
  position         : absolute;
  overflow         : hidden;
  display          : block;
  padding-left     : 10px;
  left             : 50%;
  margin-top       : 28%;
  transform        : translate(-50%);
  width            : 60%;
  height           : 20%;
  background-color : wheat;
  border-radius    : 20px;
  }
h1 {
  font-size   : 20px;
  font-weight : bolder;
  }
h2 {
  font-size : 18px;
  }
```

```html
<div navbar>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <img id="logo" src="Images/logo.png" alt="Logo F1">
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="index-v2.html">Hjem</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="main.html">Spillet</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div navbar>
<p class="characters">Velg din Karakter</p>
<div class="picture-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="show-input-on-hover">
      <img class="driver1" src="Images/verstappen.png" alt="verstappen">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="driver2" src="Images/hamilton.png" alt="hamilton">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="driver3" src="Images/leclerc.webp" alt="leclerc">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Textbox">
  <h1> Name on the driver</h1>
  <h2>Some information about the driver</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div navbar>` is incorrect HTML syntax

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) should give you what you're looking for.

```css
.Textbox {
  display: none;
}

.picture-container:hover ~ .Textbox {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: how would u go arround to make it that it is 3 different textboxes that are connected to each on of the pictures?